# Access denied for user@localhost

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I have installed xampp on Windows and am using phpmyadmin to create a database. When I paste the link of my php file corresponding to the database onto the browser I get the following error:

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'id2207666_aditijha20'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Register2.php on line 3

I tried the 'Grant Permission' command in SQL but that didn't work either.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON id2207666_perfect_fit.* TO 'id2207666_aditijha20'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

> ERROR: #1044 - Access denied for user 'id2207666_aditijha20'@'%' to database 'id2207666_perfect_fit'

How do I fix this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

there's a difference between `'id2207666_aditijha20'@'%'` and `'id2207666_aditijha20'@'localhost'`

Issue your grant for the user that you're using to connect:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON id2207666_perfect_fit.* TO 'id2207666_aditijha20'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Also, you may need to `flush privileges`